# How Can I Remove Duplicate List Elements Without Using the Set Interface?

Tags: arraylist, duplicates

```java
ArrayList<Integer>list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     list.add(1);
     list.add(2);
     list.add(1);
```

I Want To Remove Number 1 from List

I tried to delete Number using the RemoveIf method.
`list.removeIf(el->Collections.frequency(list, el)>1);`

Is There a Better Way to Remove an Number?

Answer (score 0):

This approach has a higher time complexity compared to using a Set or your original removeIf approach, especially for larger lists, because it involves nested loops. For large lists, using the Set approach or your original method is generally more efficient.

You manually iterate through the list and compare each element with the subsequent elements. If a duplicate is found, it's removed from the list. However, please note that removing elements from an ArrayList while iterating through it may lead to incorrect results or exceptions. In the code above, we adjust the index j when a removal occurs to ensure that we don't skip any elements.

```
 public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int currentElement = list.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (currentElement == list.get(j)) {
                list.remove(j);
                size--;
                j--; // Adjust the index as the list size has decreased
            }
        }
    }
}
```